# Stranges files in my assembly since switching to <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>

Tags: maven-2, line-endings, maven-assembly-plugin, fileset

since I've inserted the option `<lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>` into my fileSets and files in my Maven assembly plugin configuration, strange files are placed in my tar.

They look as following:

```
ignore.me.1499711160.filtered.903528596.formatted
run.sh.2124782621.filtered.1130667884.formatted
```

Do you know why this occurrs?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug captured in [MASSEMBLY-462](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-462). Either patch the plugin with the attached patch or revert to a previous version (try with 2.2-beta-4).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem i used excludes tag in the assembler, you can use it in pom too:

```
   <fileSet>
        <directory>DEV</directory>
        <outputDirectory>${file.separator}FileName${file.separator}DEV</outputDirectory>
        <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
        <lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>*.formatted</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </fileSet>
```

Comment: Thx that solved my problem. You could as well use `<exclude>**/*.formatted</exclude>` to make sure nested directories are also taken into account.